# Basic geolocalisation permissions for native mobile applications

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-geolocation

I did some research but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for different permissions to allow google map localisation access to my android application, I found this `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` but I don't understand how to to make it work.

Comment: Those are indeed the permissions you will use. You'll use one of them depending on your needs. A quick search on SO or google even should bring enough enough results on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this official website link that provides explanation about both permissions:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission

To quote:

> In order to receive location updates from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `GPS_PROVIDER`, you must request the user's permission by declaring either the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, respectively, in your Android manifest file. Without these permissions, your application will fail at runtime when requesting location updates.
>
> If you are using both `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`, then you
>   need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it
>   includes permission for both providers. Permission for
>   `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` allows access only to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

This means, you will only need to use one of the two in your `AndroidManifest.xml` depending on your needs as stated above.

Add the following to the manifest file and you should be good:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I don't get it all but I understand better now man, thanks. I will use the code you put and tell you if it works

Comment: If it doesn't work then you probably have another problem in your project.